# Bundler - updating gems in a particular group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

In my gemfile I have gems that are only installed in test or development group.

eg

```
group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end

group :development do
  gem "dev_gem"
end
```

Is there a way I can bundle update only the gems in these two groups?

I don't want to update ALL the gems in the Gemfile.  Just the ones in test and development.

Comment: I don't think you can, although there is an --without=<group list> option you can supply to bundler... http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/bundle-install.1.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, with

```
$ bundle update --conservative --group test development
```

Bundler’s `--conservative` option is key, because it prevents updates in any "Production" gem that is also a dependency of a "Test" or "Development" gem.

Comment: *Lovely* stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler now has this option

`bundle update <*gems> [--group=NAME] [--source=NAME] [--local]`